# How to search for variable date in Access sql

Tags: sql

I'm a bit confused why my ACCESS SQL query would act differently... When I do a SELECT query with the NOW() parameter, I get the right result. But if I use the TempVar!Date with todays date it returns 0...The queries look as follows:

This one works:

> SELECT [Account Transactions].*, Categories.*,
>   IIf([Categories].[Income/Expense]="Expense",-([Account
>   Transactions]![Transaction Amount]),[Account
>   Transactions]![Transaction Amount]) AS [Actual Amount] FROM [Account
>   Transactions] LEFT JOIN Categories ON [Account Transactions].Category
>   = Categories.ID WHERE month([Account Transactions].[Entry Date]) = month(Now());

This one doesn't work:

> SELECT [Account Transactions].*, Categories.*, IIf([Categories]. 
>   [Income/Expense]="Expense",-([Account Transactions]![Transaction
>   Amount]),[Account Transactions]![Transaction Amount]) AS [Actual
>   Amount] FROM [Account Transactions] LEFT JOIN Categories ON [Account
>   Transactions].Category = Categories.ID WHERE month([Account
>   Transactions].[Entry Date]) = month([TempVars]![Date]);

I need the second one - with my variable to work.bYour help will be greatly appreciated. I've tested the tempvar value, and it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT [Account Transactions].*, Categories.*, IIf([Categories].[Income/Expense]="Expense",-([Account Transactions]![Transaction Amount]),[Account Transactions]![Transaction Amount]) AS [Actual Amount]
FROM [Account Transactions]
LEFT JOIN Categories ON [Account Transactions].Category = Categories.ID
WHERE month([Account Transactions].[Entry Date]) = month([TempVars]![Date]);
```

I've removed some extra spaces and added in asterisks where needed.

Your TempVars values will only last for your current open session of MS Access.  What do you get when you enter `?Application.TempVars("Date").Value` in your VBA window?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was the open session that was the problem. The value was not stored everytime I tested it. Working now.